# How do I print the following array to show number 1 - 1000000

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

I want to initialize an array and fill it from 1-1000000. How do I then print the array?

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;


const int holder = 1000000;
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int nums[holder] = {0};

    for( int i = 0; i < holder; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i+1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout` is the idiomatic way of printing to the console in C++.

Comment: `int nums[] = {holder};` is wrong, it declares an array with one element initialized to the value of `holder`. You want `int nums[holder] = {0};` to declare an array with `holder` elements. When you make that change you may run into stack size issues. You can move the declaration outside main to make it global or make it static to help with that. You might consider a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `int nums[] = { holder };` creates an array with ONE element, and its value is `holder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
// First create a vector containing holder elements
std::vector<int> nums(holder);

// Then set each element to the number from 1 to holder, inclusive
std::iota(begin(nums), end(nums), 1);
```

Then to print it:

```
// Print each number in the vector, separated by newlines
for (auto num : nums)
{
    std::cout << num << '\n';
}
```

Many parts of this answer should really be part of any decent beginners book. The only "new" thing would be the [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) call.